# Rest End point not showing any json data when using POSTMAN application

Tags: spring-boot, postman, microservices

I am trying to implement sample spring boot project and trying to retrieve result using POSTMAN application. But when using POSTMAN , I am not able to see that response for a GET request. But I can see by using browser properly. POSTMAN returning "Expected ':' instead of 't'" as result. But I can see result properly by using browser.

[image]

**And my controller code is like the following,**

```
@GetMapping("/check")
    public List<Users> check() {
        return  (List<Users>) userObj.findAll();
    }
```

Can anyone help me to find out why I am not able to see result using POSTMAN application please?

Comment: @NicholasK - I did not added anythiing else . Only I have RestController annotation at top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are saying to postman (for that matter any client) that your api is producing json and instead you are returning just a string.

Check your header you will have a field called

```
Content-Type → application/json;charset=UTF-8
```

All you need to do is ensure you are sending valid json or remove that header entry so clients do not try to read it as json.
Or just to check you are getting right data by changing format from json to text in postman

[image]

Comment: Defaultly the spring boot returning the JSON. Here I am trying with List<Object> as return type.So what is happening here ? . I updated controller code. Can you please look on that ? I did not understood the actual problem.

Comment: Yes. I updated with content type. I thought that I only need to use content type in POST and PUT. So previously I was not added. Now I added. Its working.

Answer (score 0):

You server application needs to understand the incoming request type. can you define the Content-Type=application/json and give a try.